# rooting android phone to run cross compiled C file?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Do I actually need to root my phone to run a program that prints hello world?

I am trying to run a binary file after I have cross compiled it.
I get permission denied when I push the file into /data/local/tmp directory.

Any ideas where I should push it so that it can run? If possible?

Or do I need to try it on Terminal Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to have root permissions to run executable on Android.

Most likely, after pushing file to /data/local/tmp, it have no required permissions - that's why you got "permission denied". Do it as following:

```
adb push /path/to/executable /data/local/tmp
adb shell chmod 0755 /data/local/tmp/executable
adb shell 'cd /data/local/tmp && ./executable'
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I actually need to root my phone to run a program that prints hello world?

No.

> I get permission denied when I push the file into /data/local/tmp directory.

Perform a `chmod a+x` after you push it. I seem to recall the Android runtime does not understand octal. (Or maybe its the other way around based on @crystax's answer).

Comment: Thanks bro! Just needed to also clarify for those that have Android 5.0+, to cross compile, you need to add PIE flags. Or else you get only position independent executables are supported error. So add --fPIE -pie